# success with compilation error in oracle Apex while creating procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

i am trying to create procedure in oracle APEX.
when i write the following  code,it show me error:success with compilation error

```
CREATE PROCEDURE S_PRODUCTTT(
@PNAME VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
SELECT CATEGORY FROM PRODUCT WHERE PNAME=@PNAME
END;
```

kindly guide me how to resolve this error

Comment: Where in the Oracle manual did you find that syntax?

Answer (score 1):

When you're selecting something inside a procedure, the result should be assigned into a variable or an object. In your case, you have to declare a variable that will receive the data your query selects. BTW, i think your code is for sql server procedures, not oracle.In oracle, you can do it like this:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE S_PRODUCTTT(i_PNAME in VARCHAR2)
 is 
 v_category product.category%type;
 BEGIN
      SELECT CATEGORY into v_category FROM PRODUCT WHERE PNAME=i_PNAME;
 END;
```

Comment: thnx,kindly also tell me that how to insert the values through a stored procedure in oracle.

Comment: the same way you insert values in plain sql: `INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES(...)`

Comment: when i want to create procdure for other table still success with compilation error comes:Create procedure s_course27 (i_ctitle in varchar)
    is 
   V_rfee course.fee % type;
    begin
    Select fee into V_rfee from course where ctitle = i_ctitle;
    end;